# UIButton in UITableViewCell stops UITableView from scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I've two buttons in each row the buttons are in a custom UITableViewCell designed in IB

The cell has UIButton -- UIImageView -- UILabel in this order for each of the two columns

each of these two buttons recieve proper touchupInside events but I can't scroll the tableview by tapping on buttons and scrolling.

The table view can be scrolled using the space in between these two buttons.

what do I need to wire to make the tableview scroll while keeping the buttons and other views

Comment: ok all I had to do was ask the question :)

enabled user interaction on ImageView and UILabel and voila :)... it works..

Comment: Perhaps you could post your solution as an answer and then mark your answer as correct.